# Gitlab CI/CD configuration in file with specific name

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

In my project I'd like to have two separate Gitlab CI/CD configurations, each for specific Gitlab instance. These file names could look like:

- .gitlab-ci-1.yml
- .gitlab-ci-2.yml

Is that possible to specify in the Gitlab which configuration file it should use instead of using default .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. See [Specify a custom CI/CD configuration file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file).

Comment: The Q is "I'd like to have two separate Gitlab CI/CD configurations". To my knowledge you _cannot_ have more than a single pipeline definition per project. What you _can_ do is to define what name this file has (you linked to it).

Comment: The question is about two different GitLab instances.